# Using Premium Key from Alpha Vantage to get historical data from european/german stock market, but doesnt work

Tags: r, stock, alpha-vantage

I think its just a simple question. I have premium access to Alpha vantage and eod historical data, but both doesnt provide historical stock market for example for the ticker "BMW.DE".

```
install.packages("tidyquant")
library(tidyquant)
av_api_key('XXX')
ticker <- "BMW.DE"
tq_get(ticker,
       get        = "alphavantage",
       av_fun     = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY",
       interval   = "60min",
       outputsize = "full")

Warning message:
x = 'BMW.DE', get = 'alphavantager': Error: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY.. API parameters used: symbol=BMW.DE, function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY, interval=60min, outputsize=full, apikey=HIDDEN_FOR_YOUR_SAFETY
```

The same happens with eodhistorical data. I think its just not supported or do I miss something?

Second question: Provided it doesnt work, it pyhton a good alternative for that issue?

Thank you

Download intraday stock data from european market

Comment: From looking at `?tq_get` I wonder if you should have "alphavantager" for `get`, not "alphavantage", a reference to the `alphavantager` package which `tidyquant` relies on to access the alphavantage API. But perhaps the error is telling us that's not the issue. Might be worth a try anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this on, but it didint work.

Comment: You might also try using `https://github.com/business-science/alphavantager` directly to eliminate any possibility of there being an issue with the `tidyquant` wrapper translating the parameters (e.g. `ticker` vs. `symbol`...)

Comment: What you are requesting seems similar to the `alphavantager` vignette, does that work for you?

Comment: Nope didint work. I read that they get the intraday data from "Securities Information Processor (SIP) market-aggregated", it is us based. Furthermore there are no exmaples in the Intraday for european stocks. Just thinking they dont support that. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For BMW, you need to use BMW.DEX or BMW.FRK on Alpha Vantage right now.

Both symbols work for my own codes.  They also work with the generic web data request:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=BMW.DEX&outputsize=full&apikey= !!!you own premium api!!!

Ideally, Alpha Vantage should publish be a list of symbols for the stocks outside the U.S.  But I can't find that list anywhere on their site. [Has anyone figured that out yet?]